# Quadrature rule - 3rd degree polynomial and integration

Tags: real-analysis

I have the polynomial $ p(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d $. I have to show that:

$ \int_{-1}^{1} p(x) = p(- \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}) + p (\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}) $

I'm kind of stuck. My idea so far is to use "proof by symmetry" and the Newton-Cotes formula. I can see that the roots of the two functions are symmetric around the origin. Whould be very grateful for help.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$\int_{-1}^1(ax^3+bx)dx=0,$$

So

$$\int_{-1}^1P(x)dx=$$
$$\int_{-1}^1(bx^2+d)dx=\frac 23b+2d$$
and
$$P(X)+P(-X)=2bX^2+2d$$

Answer (score 1):

You easily show that by direct computation.

First notice that the odd powers will cancel out, both in the integral and in the sum.

Then

$$\int_{-1}^1(bt^2+d)\,dt=2\frac b3+2d$$

and

$$p\left(- \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right) + p \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)=2\frac b{\sqrt3^2}+2d.$$